# SpringSecurity + JS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, spring-security

Making module of registration users with activating account by email. Almost everything done, but I've met error in browser (in developers tools mode):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>   confirm?login=zzheads@gmail.com&confirmString=$2a$10$NVCbcrmlsLeM6A31HxJOqOCzfOgUno6PJ5uN3XflUZkQ.r…:694

when did 'send activation link again' function.
I have MailAPI method:

```
@RequestMapping (path = "/sendagain", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody public String sendMailAgain (@RequestBody String email) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    User user = userService.findByName(email);
    if (user != null) {
        String confirm = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getId().toString() + user.getUsername() + user.getPassword());
        String body = EmailTemplate.getHtmlCode(user.getUsername(), confirm);
        MailApi.sendMail(user.getUsername(), "www.zdelivery.ru", body, "Пожалуйста активируйте ваш аккаунт на сайте zdelivery.ru");
        return (gson.toJson("success"));
    }
    return gson.toJson("failure");
}
```

part of my login.html where I propose user send activation link again:

```
<div th:if="${emailAgain==true}" class="container">
    <div class="row col s12">
        <div class="row col s8 offset-s2 white z-depth-3">
            <div class="row center teal-text text-darken-2">
                <h5 th:text="@{'Послать еще раз ссылку активации аккаунта '+${username}}"></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s6 offset-s3">
                    <p>
                        Для отправки письма со ссылкой активации аккаунта нажмите кнопку ниже:
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row center">
                <br/>
                <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" th:onclick="@{'emailAgain('+${username}+')'}"><i class="material-icons right">send</i>Отправить</button>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my JavaScript emailAgain function:

```
function emailAgain (email) {
    console.log("emailAgain "+email);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/sendagain",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(email, null, "\t"),
        headers: {"X-CSRF-Token": $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content")},
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            // $registrationForm.children().remove();
            // $registrationForm.append(showConfirm(email));
        },
        error: getErrorMsg
    });
}
```

but when I pressed button "emailAgain" it wont call function, just browser write error message shown above.

What "token" it talking about?
How to fix it?

**UPDATE** There is no any server-side errors.
I'm sure problem is with _csrf token.
User load page from e-mail, so this request does not contain correct _csrf token. Disable _csrf defence for whole application is not a option.
How to enable request single page without _csrf?

Comment: There's no server side error ?

Comment: Verify that `CSRF` meta tag is generated on the page that is making Ajax call. Check this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html

Comment: There is no server side errors. How generate that meta tag, yep it's not generated on the page

Comment: It's given in the link which I posted in the previous comment. You can also opt to disable CSRF protection, which is also given in the same link. This may be an easier solution, if you're ok with CSRF.